# Detect when user closes pop up in iOS Safari web extension

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, safari-web-extension

I'm trying to find a way to detect when the user closes or dismisses the pop-up in an iOS Safari web extension.

I've tried listening for `onblur`, `pagehide`, and `visibilitychange` events but they are not fired when the popup is closed. All of these events do fire on macOS Safari 16, though.

Opening up a port by running `browser.runtime.connect()` in the popup and listening for onConnect/onDisconnect events in the background script only causes the onConnect event to fire when the popup is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was listening for the `blur` event. It seems to be fired only when the pop up is closed, but only if the user first taps somewhere inside the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I stumped over the same problem and discovered, that the visibility change event get only fired when:

- Visible
- Page reload

On page reload the `hidden` gets fired. But I need to get it when the popup is closed.

Looks like this is a bug but workarounds are welcome.